# Why doesn't a combined find and rename command work as expected under bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, find, rename

I have a folder full of text files of the format 'four digits, space, alphanumeric string.txt'. For example:

```
$ touch '0001 jko0001.txt'  '0002 jko0002.txt'  '0003 jko0003.txt'

$ ls
'0001 jko0001.txt'  '0002 jko0002.txt'  '0003 jko0003.txt'
```

I would like to rename the files so leading digits and space are removed. Since I have a lot of files, I am using `find` to pass filenames to `rename`. I attempted to do this with the following command:

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -n -- 's/^\d{4}\s+//' {} +`

However, this fails. (Yes, `-n` is only to print out changes without renaming the files. It fails even if I remove it).

Interestingly, if I split the command into pieces, it does work:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt'
./0003 jko0003.txt
./0002 jko0002.txt
./0001 jko0001.txt

$ rename -n -- 's/^[0-9]{4}\s+//' *.txt
0001 jko0001.txt -> jko0001.txt
0002 jko0002.txt -> jko0002.txt
0003 jko0003.txt -> jko0003.txt

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

But when combined with `xargs`, it fails. Why?

Also, I can't even get it working with `find`'s `-execdir`:

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir rename -n -- 's/^\d{4} //' {} \;`

None of these work.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -n -- 's/^\d{4}\s+//' "{}" +
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -n -- 's/^[0-9]{4}\s+//' "{}" +
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir rename -n -- 's/^\d{4} //' {} \;
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir rename -n -- 's/^\d{4} //' '{}' \;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the files are all in the current directory, then `find` is not necessary.

Comment: Absolutely, see my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two problems here. First, `find` is passing a path to the file, not just the filename (yes, even with `-execdir`). So add the `-d` option to `rename`, to tell it to just act on just the filename, not the full path.

Second, you're mixing `find -exec` syntax up with `xargs`. Specifically, the `{} +` at the end of the command is something you'd use with `find -exec`, *not* with `xargs` (note: in some modes, `xargs` uses `{}` like this, but it never uses `+`). To fix it, either remove the `{} +` and use standard `xargs` syntax:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -n -d -- 's/^\d{4}\s+//'
rename(./0003 jko0003.txt, ./jko0003.txt)
rename(./0001 jko0001.txt, ./jko0001.txt)
rename(./0002 jko0002.txt, ./jko0002.txt)
```

Or skip `xargs`, and use `find -exec` directly (this time *with* the `{} +`):

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec rename -n -d -- 's/^\d{4}\s+//' {} +
rename(./0003 jko0003.txt, ./jko0003.txt)
rename(./0001 jko0001.txt, ./jko0001.txt)
rename(./0002 jko0002.txt, ./jko0002.txt)
```

BTW, when troubleshooting problems like this, it's sometimes helpful to put `echo` in front of the problem command to get an idea what arguments are being passed to it:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 echo rename -n -- 's/^\d{4}\s+//' {} +
rename -n -- s/^\d{4}\s+// {} + ./0003 jko0003.txt ./0001 jko0001.txt ./0002 jko0002.txt
                           ^^^^ this is the problem
```

But that's sometimes misleading, since (among other things) it loses the distinction between spaces within arguments and spaces *between* arguments. Replacing `echo` with `printf '%q\n'` is sometime better (although it has other problems, and not all external `printf` implementations support `%q`).

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon! I did a lot of searching and reading man pages and couldn't figure it out. I see the error or my ways <3.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895), **as far as you use current directory, no need `find | xargs rename`**:

```
$ rename -n 's|^\./\d{4}\s+||' ./*.txt
rename(./0001 jko0001.txt, jko0001.txt)
rename(./0002 jko0002.txt, jko0002.txt)
rename(./0003 jko0003.txt, jko0003.txt)
```

Take in account that you have leading `./` on each files

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

---

In a **recursive** way, without `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar # needed for bash, not zsh
rename -n 's|^\./\d{4}\s+||' ./**/*.txt
```