# Capitalize first letter of all subfolders and files with bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename all my folders and its files so that the first letter is a capital.

I've got this script which does that for the current directory:

`rename -f 's/./\U$&/' *`

This is working great. How can I run this command in every subfolder (`**/*`)?

Comment: Since you are using bash, you must first enable `**`: `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: But which `rename` are you using? According to [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), there is no `-f` option for `rename`.

Comment: I used `brew install rename`. Got this working with a warning that files are not directories but does the job: `for d in ./**/* ; do (cd "$d" && rename -f 's/./\U$&/' *); done`

Comment: ^ Actually skips current directory which should also be included

Comment: Then include the current directory, by doing just `**/*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running a few tests and jumping around the forums, I put together the following:

```
find . -depth -execdir rename -f 's/./\U$&/' {} +
```

The [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux/54163971#54163971) to a similar question does a great job explaining the `-depth` and `-execdir` options and why they're necessary for this particular scenario. I was struggling to get it to work until I swapped `-exec` with `-execdir`!

[Find multiple files and rename them in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux/54163971#54163971)

Comment: Thank you, there were indeed other similar questions but I couldn't get it to work. This one works like a charm.

Comment: Shouldn't there be also a `-type f`? With your command, directories would be renamed as well.

Comment: @user1934428 `-type f` can be used to specify files, but OP requested both directories and files: "I'm trying to rename all my folders and its files so that the first letter is a capital."

Comment: Right you are! Final question: What is the `-f` doing with `rename`? I didn't find this option documented in the man-page.

Comment: @user1934428 -f in rename forces the operation despite warnings (specifically `-f/--force or -i/--interactive (proceed or prompt when overwriting) ` when typing `rename -h`), which is useful in this case because rename will stall on identical filenames in different directories without this option

Answer (score 0):

For recursive solution `find` command can be used with `rename`. With `find` recursive modification or filteration could be used for specific file/folder type.

Here is the solution I've tested in my WSL Ubuntu:

```
find . -exec rename -d 's/./\U$&/' {} +
```

This question is kind of duplicate. Similar question is : [Use find command with rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081729/why-doesnt-a-combined-find-and-rename-command-work-as-expected-under-bash-shell#:%7E:text=First%2C%20find%20is%20passing%20a%20path%20to%20the,you%27re%20mixing%20find%20-exec%20syntax%20up%20with%20xargs.)

My solution here is derived/changed from above linked question/solution.